# Codeigniter: multiple COUNT and SUM from one table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have MySQL table as follow:

```
id | ads | status | user_id |
```

What would be best way to get:

1. count of all rows `where user_id=1 and status=1`
2. count of all rows `where user_id=1 and status=0`
3. sum of all ads `where user_id=0`
4. sum of all ads `where user_id=1`

My question: Can I run only one query to get all 4 results? If so, would you please explain how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And how do you want to do it? why codeigniter, do you want to do it with Active Record?

Comment: Actually it can be regular MySQL query; disregard CI. Also I can get results by running 2 queries: one for condition: status=1; another query when status=0 ... But wonder if all of that can be done by running one single query.

Comment: Well, I thought it better, maybe with the query below you can do it, :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(if(status=1 and user_id=X, 1, 0)) as V1,
sum(if(status=1 and user_id=X, ads, 0)) as V2,
sum(if(status=0 and user_id=X, 1, 0)) as V3,
sum(if(status=0 and user_id=X, ads, 0)) as V4
FROM table)
```

Comment: XD, I see, I had to put all with sum, :P